# VS2013 Extensions, VSIX project does not show Item Templates

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-addins, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

I downloaded and installed SDK, after that I'm able to see project templates and I created first VSIX Project.  But when I right click the project to add Item Templates like "Custom Command" or "Custom Tool Window" there is even no Extensions node available in "Add New Item" window.  for reference see image below.  I even try searching templates but no luck.  (Working with VS2013 Ultimate C# project)

[image]

Comment: I don't have these either. Where did you see 'Custom Command' and 'Custom Tool Window'? I've never heard of these (as templates).

Comment: I came across this page https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/ide/extensions/hello_world but later found that its about VS2015 but they did not mention it in article.

Comment: Currently I'm trying to develop extension that allow me a button on tool bar which opens a window (form) by clicking a button on that form I want to add new class.cs file to solution and then it paste some text from clipboard to class.cs.

Can you please guide me what I need for this task, so that I can start searching resources on that direction.

Comment: That's a lot of steps :-) Adding a button: search "vsix add command vsct". Adding a file to a project: Probably the easiest is with EnvDTE's `Project.ProjectItems.AddFromFile` method. Opening it can be done with `VsShellUtilities.OpenDocument`. Pasting from the clipboard can be done by sending the `VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.Paste` command from the `VSConstants.GUID_VSStandardCommandSet97`.